# ASP .NET MVC 5 Video Conferencing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-5

I know this question has been asked many times here but seems to be very old. Can you please help me to understand what are best approach ASP.NET MVC have to integrate video chat/conference in my website.

Answer (score 0):

You need some objects to add video chat so you can go with Silverlight and you can add it using the following code:

```xml
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
    <param name="source" value="ClientBin/yoursilverlight.xap"/>
    <param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError" />
    <param name="background" value="white" />
    <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="2.0.31005.0" />
    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
    <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=124807" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style: none"/>
    </a>
</object>
```

where clientBin is the folder where silverlight xap is located and yoursilverlight.xap is the xap name.

Comment: Thanks. can we do the same in html5 video getusermedia

Comment: Has anyone has answer for this please. I am tired of searching over internet but did not find anything.